# Gcm android application triggers multiple registrations for the same device

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

My GCM app generate multiple registrations for same device. I have searched for this but coud'nt find any solution.

Here is my main activity::

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, "952039800261");
    } else {
      Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");

    }}
```

And this is my onRegistered() method::

```
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, final String regId) {

Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
// sets the app name in the intent
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderId);
startService(registrationIntent);


   // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ludlowcastle.co.in/moksha/register.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regId));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

I have got around 5K registrations IDs for same device on my server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering in an infinite loop.

I don't use the `GCMRegistrar` class, but I'm quite sure that `GCMRegistrar.register(this, "952039800261");` does the same as these lines :

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
// sets the app name in the intent
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderId);
startService(registrationIntent);
```

In my app, these 4 lines are in the `onCreate` method of my main activity instead of the `GCMRegistrar` call.

When `onRegistered` is called, this means the registration has been successful and you have a registration id. Since you are asking in this method to register again, a new registration request is sent to Google, and then this method is called again when the next registration succeeds. I'm not sure if you are getting different registration IDs on each call, or if you get the same one, but simply removing the mentioned 4 lines from `onRegistered` will solve your problem.